# Issue with bytes and integers in Python while working with Flask-Login

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

Essentially I'm trying to define a user loader using `flask-login` and with that I have to pass through my user's database id. I'm getting some sort of invalid literal error.

I've tried converting this 'byte?' from integer to string and all sorts, I've tried decoding it with several methods such as `UTF-8` and still no luck.

```py
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return accounts.query.get(int(str(id)))
```

Here is the error that is thrown out to me by the console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 259, in decorated_view
    elif not current_user.is_authenticated:
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 348, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 307, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 335, in _get_user
    current_app.login_manager._load_user()
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 359, in _load_user
    return self.reload_user()
  File "d:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\env\lib\site-packages\flask_login\login_manager.py", line 321, in reload_user
    user = self.user_callback(user_id)
  File "D:\Programming\Python (Flask)\MRP UCP\app.py", line 25, in load_user
    return accounts.query.get(int(str(id)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'5'"
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2019 09:12:10] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I am on the latest version of `sqlalchemy`, `flask-sqlalchemy`, `flask-login`. I am also using `bcrypt` and a couple other things in my script such as `urandom` for the secret key and some time tracking things.

Help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You are turning the byte `b'5'` to the string `"b'5'"` so your string contains the letter b and the single quotes. `int` does not understand such messy strings, what you should do is simply remove the `str` function:

```
return accounts.query.get(int(id))
```

Comment: ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "b'5'"
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Mar/2019 09:42:42] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 500 -``` Still the exact same issue appears.

Comment: what is the `type` of id? what does the command `type(id)` return?

Comment: i assume its a integer. this is sqlalchemy im working with. this might help ya, https://pastebin.com/ibzchXWu

Comment: don't [assume](https://xkcd.com/1339/), please check, print it if you have to, it appears to be a string but you should make sure

Comment: It returns ```b'5'```.

Comment: if its `b'5'` then `int(b'5')` should work. are you 100% sure? whats the `type` of it?

Comment: Nevermind, the type that was returned is ```<class 'str'>```.

Comment: as foretold by prophecy.

Comment: I suppose I'm not getting any help then?

Comment: i thought you figured it out, where does this `id` come from? go back up to where you get it from and don't make it a string, if for some reason you cant do that, you can remove the head and tail with `int(id[2:-1],16) `

Comment: I hope I did mention I'm working with flask. It's a user account. Here is a link to the pastebin I posted on the 31st of March. https://pastebin.com/ibzchXWu

Comment: I got it sorted with the help of a guy on a Python discord guild. My issue was that `UserMixin` had to be before `db.Model` and that my `ID` column should've been `id`. My code now works perfectly fine.